# Optional prefix on express route

Tags: node.js, express

I've got a route like the following `foo-bar/my/cool/path`, however I'd like to treat `foo-bar` as an optional so that both `my/cool/path` and `foo-bar/my/cool/path` route to my endpoint. I've tried using `:foo-bar?` but it seems to not like the `-` I have in my prefix, any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is wrapping the route callback in a function :

```
const callbackFunc = (res, req) => {}
```

and apply it to your two routes :

```
app.get('/foo-bar/my/cool/path', callbackFunc)

app.get('/my/cool/path', callbackFunc)
```